# SciPy minimize: providing only odd integer numbers as a parameter to the cost function

Tags: python, scipy-optimize-minimize, differential-evolution

I'm trying to apply `minimize` from the **SciPy** `optimize` module to a cost function of my own:

```
result = minimize(cost_function, initial_params, args = (TEXT_IMG, BINARY_MASK), method = 'BFGS')
```

I need the first param to be an odd integer number, like 31:

```
initial_params = np.array([31, 2, -7])
```

But minimize starts iterating around 31, with just float numbers, and my cost function crashes; is it possible to implement bounds and constraints so minimize keeps providing numbers like 31, 29, 33, etc.?

I have read that I might need to use `differential_evolution` instead of `minimize`, but just to make sure.

**EDIT**:

This is the cost function:

```
def abs_diff(mask1, mask2):

    diff = np.abs(mask1 - mask2)
    mean_diff = np.mean(diff)

    return mean_diff

def cost_function(params, text_img, binary_mask):
    
    blockSize, C, h = params
    hColor = -3
    templateWSize = 5
    searchWSize = 5

    denoised = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(text_img, h, hColor, templateWSize, searchWSize)
    gray_denoised = cv2.cvtColor(denoised, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    imgf = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_denoised, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, blockSize, C)

    error = abs_diff(binary_mask * 255, imgf)
            
    return error
```

Comment: Can you show the cost function?

Answer (score 1):

Methods like BFGS are not so good for discrete-valued parameters.

The pragmatic solution is to run your optimization for all 16 `blockSize` values and pick the best result.

Or you could "cheat" by scaling and rounding the `blockSize` before use in such a way that the initial distribution has a good coverage.

If you have more discrete parameters (especially boolean ones), then another option is to see this problem as **hyper-parameter optimization**. Either just do random search over those parameters, or use something like [ray tune](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/tutorials/tune-search-spaces.html), which is basically a parallel random search that also supports early stopping on the inner "training loop" when it starts looking bad. (The inner loop would optimize the remaining continuous parameters with a stronger algorithm than random search.)

Another alternative would be the CEM (Cross-Entropy Method), which allows mixing discrete and continuous distributions. But for real-valued parameters it may converge to a much worse solutions than something like BFGS. A genetic algorithm may work, too, but given that you're using scipy.optimize it will probably involve too much setup and hand-crafting.